# Combine 2 JCR-SQL2 queries to 1 query

Tags: adobe, aem, jcr-sql2, adobe-exprience-manager

I need to merge these 2 queries together:

**Query 1**

> SELECT page.* FROM [cq:Page] AS page INNER JOIN [nt:base] AS component
> ON isdescendantnode(component,page) WHERE
> component.[sling:resourceType]
> ='wcm/foundation/components/responsivegrid'

This query returns all pages that have the component of resource type `wcm/foundation/components/responsivegrid`

**Query 2**

> SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE
> ISDESCENDANTNODE([/content/en-us/homepage/jcr:content])

This query returns all components under `jcr:content` that the page path with "/content/en-us/homepage"

I would like to use the list of page urls from from query 1 and apply on query 2 and replace this path "/content/en-us/homepage".

Here's what I have but it shows an error of  `expected: static operand`:

> SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE s.[sling:resourceType]
> ='wcm/foundation/components/responsivegrid' AND s.[jcr:path] IN ( SELECT page.[jcr:path] FROM [cq:Page] AS page INNER JOIN [nt:base] AS
> component ON isdescendantnode(component, page) WHERE
> component.[sling:resourceType]
> ='wcm/foundation/components/responsivegrid' )

What should be the right syntax in JCR-SQL2?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?